# how can i start an animation on touch which will stop after reaching the end of spritesheet?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I wanted to create a kicking animation when user touch the screen. I call a function from `render(){}` like this

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
         if(lr.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())){
             //start animation 1-2-3-3-2-1 complete kick
             myAnimation(); //this is my function. code below,
             batch.begin();
             sprite.draw(batch);
             batch.end();
         }
}
```

`myAnimation()` is where i create a new task. to understand every movement i kept interval 5sec.

**myAnimation()**

```
private void myAnimation(){
    Timer.schedule(new Task() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(positiveCycle){
                currentFrame++;
                if(currentFrame>3) {
                    positiveCycle = false; 
                    currentFrame = 3;
                }
            }else{
                currentFrame--;
                if(currentFrame==0){
                    //get out of this loop
                    currentFrame = 1;
                    positiveCycle = true;
                    this.cancel();
                }
            }
            currentAtlasKey = String.format("%04d", currentFrame);
            sprite.setRegion(textureAtlas.findRegion(currentAtlasKey));
        }
    }
}
```

But when I touch the screen i do not see each spite after 5 sec interval, Its kind of very quick to show the sprite. like less then 20 milliseconds.

**The complete code**

```
package com.geek.tanvir.KickingGame;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GLTexture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer.Task;

public class KickingGame implements ApplicationListener {
private OrthographicCamera camera;

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texturePlayer;
private Texture texturePlayerKick;
private Texture texturePlayerKick2;
private Texture texturePlayer2;
private Texture ball;
private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
private Sprite sprite;
private int currentFrame = 1;
private String currentAtlasKey = new String("0001");
int currentframe = 1;
private boolean positiveCycle = true;
//private Sprite sprite;
private Rectangle lr;
private Rectangle rr;

@Override
public void create() {      
    //float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    //float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);

    texturePlayer = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player.jpg"));
    texturePlayerKick = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("playerKick.jpg"));
    texturePlayer2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player2.jpg"));
    texturePlayerKick2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("playerKick2.jpg"));
    ball = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball.jpg"));

    lr = new Rectangle();
    rr = new Rectangle();

    textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("sheet.atlas"));
    AtlasRegion region = textureAtlas.findRegion("0001");
    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setPosition(120, 100);
    sprite.scale(0.02f);

    lr.set(0, 0, 400, 400);
    rr.set(400, 0, 400, 400);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    texturePlayer.dispose();
    texturePlayer2.dispose();
    texturePlayerKick.dispose();
    texturePlayerKick2.dispose();
    ball.dispose();
}

private void myAnimation(){
    Timer.schedule(new Task() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(positiveCycle){
                currentFrame++;
                if(currentFrame>3) {
                    positiveCycle = false; 
                    currentFrame = 3;
                }
            }else{
                currentFrame--;
                if(currentFrame==0){
                    //get out of this loop
                    currentFrame = 1;
                    positiveCycle = true;
                    this.cancel();
                }
            }
            currentAtlasKey = String.format("%04d", currentFrame);
            sprite.setRegion(textureAtlas.findRegion(currentAtlasKey));
        }
    }, 5, 5);
}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texturePlayer, 300-texturePlayer.getWidth(),100);
    batch.draw(texturePlayer2, 500, 100);
    batch.draw(ball, 400-ball.getWidth(),500-ball.getHeight());

    batch.end();
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
         if(lr.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())){
             //start animation 1-2-3-3-2-1 complete kick
             myAnimation();
             batch.begin();
             sprite.draw(batch);
             batch.end();
         }
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

Comment: Conceptual answer is appreciated.

Comment: Animation will end after completing a complete cycle, like 1-2-3-3-2-1      (sprites in spritesheet).

Comment: Are you trying to make an animation where the sprite only shows while the user is still touching?

Comment: No, That was a mistake sprite.draw() should be outside the if condition. It tried it but i did not get desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to show a `Sprite`, which stands stil, until the user touches. Then it makes the `Animation` and if it is done it stands stil again, until the user touches again right? 
For this use the [Animation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html) and use its 2nd constructor:

```
Animation myAnim = new Animation(frameDuration, animationTextures, PlayMode.Normal);
```

Then store a `boolean animating = false;` as well as a `float stateTime = 0;`

If the user touches you set `animating = true;`

In the render say:

```
if (animating) {
    stateTime+=delta;
    TextureRegion currentFrame = myAnim.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
    // draw the currentFrame
    if(myAnim. isAnimationFinished(stateTime)) {
        animating = false;
        stateTime = 0;
    }
}
else {
   // draw the unanimated Frame;
}
```

Something to read: [Animation API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html)
[Tutorial on GitHub](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation)

Comment: Thanks. I did it almost the same way. Now I know few more extra stuffs from your ans. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. SO is here to help. If you have any more questions feel free to ask